# creating multiple index on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to convert a data-frame to a dict in the below format:

```
name    age     country     state   pincode
user1   10      in          tn      1
user2   11      in          tx      2
user3   12      eu          gh      3
user4   13      eu          io      4
user5   14      us          pi      5
user6   15      us          ew      6
```

the output groups users based on countries and had a dictionary of users with the details of users inside a dictionary

```
{
  'in': {
          'user1': {'age': 10, 'state': 'tn', 'pincode': 1},
          'user2': {'age': 11, 'state': 'tx', 'pincode': 2}
        },
 'eu':  {
          'user3': {'age': 12, 'state': 'gh', 'pincode': 3},
          'user4': {'age': 13, 'state': 'io', 'pincode': 4},
        },
 'us': { 
          'user5': {'age': 14, 'state': 'pi', 'pincode': 5},
          'user6': {'age': 15, 'state': 'ew', 'pincode': 6},
       }
}
```

I am currently doing this by below statement(this is not completely correct as i am using a list inside the loop, instead it should have been a dict):

```
op2 = {}
for i, row in sample2.iterrows():
    if row['country'] not in op2:
            op2[row['country']] = []
    op2[row['country']] = {row['name'] : {'age':row['age'],'state':row['state'],'pincode':row['pincode']}}
```

I want a the solution to work if there are additional columns added to the df. for example telephone number. Since the statement I have written is static it won't give me the additional rows in my output. Is there a built in method in pandas that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `to_dict` with `groupby`:

```
{k:v.drop('country',axis=1).to_dict('i') 
    for k,v in df.set_index('name').groupby('country')}
```

Output:

```
{'eu': {'user3': {'age': 12, 'state': 'gh', 'pincode': 3},
  'user4': {'age': 13, 'state': 'io', 'pincode': 4}},
 'in': {'user1': {'age': 10, 'state': 'tn', 'pincode': 1},
  'user2': {'age': 11, 'state': 'tx', 'pincode': 2}},
 'us': {'user5': {'age': 14, 'state': 'pi', 'pincode': 5},
  'user6': {'age': 15, 'state': 'ew', 'pincode': 6}}}
```

Comment: how do i approach this when my index is not unique. for example when username repeats in a different country

Comment: It should still work, listing all `username` within each country.